# Nvidia settings only opens a small blank window

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, opengl

I am trying to get Nvidia drivers to work, however when I open Nvidia settings only a small blank window opens (shown in the screenshot along with the output from `nvidia-smi` command).

I have installed the driver by running the following commands:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
sudo reboot
```

I have tried purging and reinstalling the driver multiple times, which didn't change anything.

Any suggestions on how to get Nvidia settings to work would be appreciated.

System: remote server with Ubuntu 18.04, with the visual output through KDE Plasma + Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.40       Driver Version: 430.40       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   37C    P8     7W / 200W |     54MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1273      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             9MiB |
|    0      1339      G   /usr/bin/sddm-greeter                         42MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Error message when running `nvidia-settings` or `sudo nvidia-settings`:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system                                                                                                                               


(nvidia-settings:2278): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:28:34.205: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed                                                            
** Message: 13:28:34.206: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 13:28:34.206: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

[image: (screenshot)]

Comment: I've always avoided Nvidia hardware so lack familiarity but it's possible that `nvidia-settings` should be run with superuser privileges (sudo). Some utility programs print vague, unhelpful errors due to not having sufficient permissions. Also, the question could be improved by editing it to *also* include a textual copy and past of the terminal contents. Keep the screenshot as it's useful for showing how the window is mostly blank; adding the text makes it easier to see the useful details. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited my question accordingly. Unfortunately running with super user privileges does not change anything, giving the exact same result.

Comment: I thought it might be worth a shot. :( All I can do is give you an upvote for asking a good/useful question and hope somebody more knowledgeable can answer it for you.